# Travis CI No Binary for 2.1.0 Found

Tags: ruby, travis-ci, ruby-2.1

I've just updated a gem to run its tests with Ruby 2.1.0, but it seems that there is no binary on Travis.  I've been looking around the internet and can't find anything definitive.

Here is a link to the build: https://travis-ci.org/Ahsizara/cached_resource/jobs/24171298

Here is the exact output:

```
Using worker: worker-linux-6-1.bb.travis-ci.org:travis-linux-16
Applying updates
git.1
$ git clone --depth=50 --branch=master git://github.com/Ahsizara/cached_resource.git Ahsizara/cached_resource
Cloning into 'Ahsizara/cached_resource'...
remote: Counting objects: 358, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (206/206), done.
remote: Total 358 (delta 151), reused 337 (delta 133)
Receiving objects: 100% (358/358), 53.19 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (151/151), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
$ cd Ahsizara/cached_resource
git.3
$ git checkout -qf 30f2ddae11a4bcdb4640547041fd6531dc7679a4
$ rvm use 2.1.0 --install --binary --fuzzy
/home/travis/.rvm/scripts/functions/selector_parse: line 18: __list_remote_ruby_for: command not found
2.1.0 is not installed - installing.
/home/travis/.rvm/scripts/functions/selector_parse: line 18: __list_remote_ruby_for: command not found
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Requested binary installation but no rubies are available to download, consider skipping --binary flag.
Gemset '' does not exist, 'rvm 2.1.0 do rvm gemset create ' first, or append '--create'.
The command "rvm use 2.1.0 --install --binary --fuzzy" failed and exited with 2 during setup.
Your build has been stopped.`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is being discussed on the travis-ci github issues.  See [issue #2220](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/2220).